# Difference (int) & FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

Tags: php

I want to sanitize user input in PHP by only accepting a number.

What's the difference between the following, because I've always been using the first one, but wanted to know for sure which one is safer to use and why:

```
$lastchange = (int)$_POST["lastchange"];
```

and

```
$lastchange = filter_var($_POST["lastchange"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: Here's the difference https://3v4l.org/KtrqM

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of `filter_var($_POST['lastchange']` you should use `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastchange'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear now :)

Answer (score 4):

`(int)` will cast the string to an integer, which will take any numbers from the beginning, and stop when it can't find any more numbers. If there are no numbers or other characters in front of the numbers, it will return 0.

`filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)` will, as the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) says, `Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.`.

Here are a few examples:

```
$var = 'a1b2c3d4'; 
echo (int)$var; // 0
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // 1234

$var = '$1.45';
echo (int)$var; // 0
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // 145

$var = '1.45';

echo (int)$var; // 1
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // 145

$var = '100 thousand 5 hundred + 6 pounds';
echo (int)$var; // 100
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // 1005+6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear now :)